# Can you get the mouse position with javascript when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent

I have a codepen setup that gets the mouse position on the document using `window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mousemoveFn);`, however, if you begin scrolling, the interactions will not work with the mouse position until you move it again. So my question is this:

Is there any way to get the current mouse position on the page using the event listener for scroll?
`window.addEventListener('scroll', callback);`

Since the position is being retrieved using the event off of mousemove, I'm not sure this is possible, but it would be great to have the elements interact with the mouse cursor as you scroll as well as when you move the mouse.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/IamBramer/pen/zavoBp

Comment: Can you just save the last known mouse position and use that on scroll?

Comment: @CoryKleiser that sounds like a route that could work. You'd have to save the last known position, as well as what the scroll position was when the mouse stopped moving, then as you scroll add the new scroll position to the last known mouse position to get the new mouse position. I like your thinking. Still curious if there as any built in behaviors to access the position easier though.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer:

> Is there any way to get the current mouse position on the page using the event listener for scroll?

see the event definition from [MDN wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel):

```
        var event = {
            // keep a ref to the original event object
            originalEvent: originalEvent,
            target: originalEvent.target || originalEvent.srcElement,
            type: "wheel",
            deltaMode: originalEvent.type == "MozMousePixelScroll" ? 0 : 1,
            deltaX: 0,
            deltaY: 0,
            deltaZ: 0,
            preventDefault: function() {
                originalEvent.preventDefault ?
                    originalEvent.preventDefault() :
                    originalEvent.returnValue = false;
            }
        };
```

No properties with the mouse position in this object (think about swipe, no position, just a direction **vector**).

Now to answer:

> to have the **elements** interact with the mouse cursor as you scroll as well as when you move the mouse

You should use the [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) event, and the [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) event, on your **elements** directly, or even the [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) event.

Browser does the job for you to know if the mouse **enters, leaves,** or is **over** an element, whenever you scroll or move.

As a comment, mouse events are common-sense events, if nothing happens (mouse does not move), nothing happens, no move event.
In fact, any [hook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318804/how-to-set-a-windows-hook-in-visual-c-net) can change the position of the the mouse without your browser being notified (receive the lower level Event), thus not reacting.